# Angularjs - unable to resolve a required dependency when trying to use a global service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a function which is used in more than 1 controller, so I thought to create a service and use it globally.

That's why I included a file commonService.js in my index.html

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myAppName');
myApp.service(['loadHttpService', '$window', '$http', function (loadHttpService, $window, $http) {
    this.loadHttpService = function (url) {
        ...
        };
        return $http.jsonp(url, {
                params: {
                    callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                ...
            });    
    };
}]);
```

and used it in my homeController, including the service as dependency, as below:

```
'use strict';    
angular.module('Home') 
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', '$state', 'loadHttpService',   
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $window, $state, loadHttpService) {
        ...
        var url = "http://xxx";
        loadHttpService.loadHttp(url);

    }]);
```

But this is leading me to such error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=loadHttpServiceProvider%20%3C-%20loadHttpService%20%3C-%20HomeController

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Please note: myAppName is the name of my app (used in ng-app).

I am very new to angularjs and feel free to add any tip to do it in a better way.

Comment: You re creating two different angular modules.

Comment: that's because myAppName is for my app, and Home is a module for homecontroller

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I believe you can't import across modules.

Comment: The first mistake I can see in you code is : You are injecting `$scope` in a service (Which you are not supposed to). So, just remove `$scope` from dependency in your service and try running it. If error persists update your question.

Comment: @Achu, I removed it but there are no change in my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many way to skin a cat or inject dependencies

> module1 - common

```
angular.module('commonServices', [])
  .service('myService', function () { //look ma, a service})
```

> module2

```
angular.module('superApp', ['commonServices'])
  .controller('notMyCtrl', function (myService) { //look ma, a service from other module})
```

> module3

```
angular.module('homeApp', ['commonServices'])
  .controller('homeCtrl', function (myService) { //look ma, a service from other module})
```

or in the same way you can inject `home` module into parent module (i can't imagine benefits of bootstraping 2 apps in one page)

Comment: please, could you rephrase the answer?

Comment: I see you have two modules: `angular.module('myAppName')` and `angular.module('Home') ` I guess you dont want to boostrap both modules with `ngApp` or manually. Are you injecting one module into another?

Comment: myAppName is the name of my app (as used in ng-app)

Comment: if you define your module like: `angular.module('myAppName', ['home'])` taking that you have `angular.module('Home')` then you can service/controller on whichever module and you will have access to it. Remember that: `angular.module('Home')` is getter and `angular.module('Home'. [])` is setter for module